# Can KNN be overfit by adding too many variables?

Tags: machine-learning, overfitting, k-nearest-neighbour, degrees-of-freedom

GLMs can be overfit by adding too many variables. However, since with knn you are not estimating parameters, surely you are not using up degrees of freedom. So would this mean that you cannot overfit knn based on the number of variables you use, simply on the basis of the value of K that you choose?

(This is of course assuming that the additional variables used are sufficiently relevant)